# How to create a simple app with Apache Cordova with Phaser 3?

Tags: android, ios, swift, cordova, phaser-framework

I want to know how to integrate Phaser 3 with Apache Cordova, I was seeing a some documentation that showed a simple game with airplane into mobile app generated by Cordova.

This is de documentation: [Creating Mobile Games with Phaser 3 and Cordova](https://gamedevacademy.org/creating-mobile-games-with-phaser-3-and-cordova/)

But it tested on an old version of Cordova (2019). I tried with actual version and it shows a empty layout.

I tried generate the website version with Web Browser plugin for Cordova. But the console doesn't shows any response. So I think that Phasers library isn't loading by Cordova.

Is there some way for integrate Cordova with Phaser 3 or some documentation?

Comment: Is your question answered? or do you need some more information?

Answer (score 2):

Well this is how I got it running *(**aka** the minimal setup needed, for phaser)*:

1. get the default cordova app to run. You can do that following this guide: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/11.x/guide/cli/index.html
   *(It was a bit tricky for me, since I'm using windows, but following the guide should work fine)*
2. add the `phaser.min.js` file and any assets to the project (in my case `game.js` and `logo.png`).
3. update the `index.html`:

   - add the javscript files, in may case `phaser.min.js` and `game.js`

     - `phaser.min.js` downloaded from here: https://phaser.io/download/stable
     - `game.js` I adapted this basic example-code from https://github.com/proyecto26/ion-phaser and https://stackoverflow.com/a/71302855/1679286
   - **Important** I tripped over this on android, update the *meta-tag* `Content-Security-Policy` to include `blob:` for `img-src`:

     `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';  media-src *; img-src 'self' data: content: blob:;">`

And than it runs.

**Here the relevant code:**
*(**Information:** this resizing and example is base on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71302855/1679286)*

```js
const config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    orientation: Phaser.Scale.LANDSCAPE,
    autoRound: true,
    autoFocus: true,
    scale: {
        autoCenter: Phaser.Scale.CENTER_BOTH,
        mode: Phaser.Scale.RESIZE,
    },
    backgroundColor: '#000',
    scene: {
        preload() {
            this.load.image('logo', '/assets/logo.png');
        },
        create() {
            let {width, height} = this.sys.game.canvas;
            let logo = this.add.image(width/2, height/3, 'logo');
            this.tweens.add({
                targets: logo,
                y: (height*2)/3,
                duration: 2000,
                ease: 'Power2',
                yoyo: true,
                loop: -1,
            });
        }
    },
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {
            gravity: { y: 100 },
            debug: true
        }
    },
};

window.addEventListener('load', async () => {
    game.scale.once('resize', function(gameSize, baseSize, displaySize){ 
        game.scene.scenes[0].physics.world.setBounds(0, 0, displaySize.width, displaySize.height);
    });
    game.scale.refresh();
});

document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

let game;

function onDeviceReady() {
    game = new Phaser.Game(config);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
            content="default-src 'self' data: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';  media-src *; img-src 'self' data: content: blob:;">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width, viewport-fit=cover">
        <meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
        <title>My FirstGame</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script src="js/phaser.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/game.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```